# iPhone: Confused about what this method declaration is saying

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods

I am new to iPhone.  Can someone explain this method declaration to me:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *) error{
```

Here is what I am guessing:

- `(void)` - method does not return anything
- `locationManager:` - ???
- `(CLLocationManager *)manager` - this looks like a parameter.  To a CLLocationManager.
- `didFailWithError:` - This seems like the method name
- `(NSError *) error` - This also seems like a parameter.  I am somewhat confused about why there are parameters in two locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a a look here: http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/

Comment: Thanks very very helpful.  Exactly what I was looking for sometimes hard to find those when you are starting a new language.

Answer (score 2):

This is Objective C, not regular C, so the function name is interspersed with the parameters.  `locationManager` and `didFailWithError` are both part of the function name.

Comment: Method name, not function name... but,yup.